# R Regular Expression Lookbehind

Tags: regex, r, package, text-mining

I have a vector filled with strings of the following format: `<year1><year2><id1><id2>`

the first entries of the vector looks like this:

```
199719982001
199719982002
199719982003
199719982003
```

For the first entry we have: year1 = 1997, year2 = 1998, id1 = 2, id2 = 001.

I want to write a regular expression that pulls out year1, id1, and the digits of id2 that are not zero. So for the first entry the regex should output: 199721.

I have tried doing this with the stringr package, and created the following regex:

```
"^\\d{4}|\\d{1}(?<=\\d{3}$)"
```

to pull out year1 and id1, however when using the lookbehind i get a "invalid regular expression" error. This is a bit puzzling to me, can R not handle lookaheads and lookbehinds?

Comment: look at the help page `regex`. Lookbehind is supported for `perl=TRUE`. So `regexp("^\\d{4}|\\d{1}(?<=\\d{3}$)",s)` does not throw an error, but does not select what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I knew that the regex would not capture all, I was just experimenting a bit - and got stomped when I kept getting an "invalid regular expression" message.

Comment: With `strapply` in gsubfn this regular expression works and does not require lookahead or lookbehind: `L <- c("199719982001", "199719982002", "199719982003", "199719982003"); library(gsubfn); strapply(L, "^(....)....(.)0*(.*)", c, simplify = TRUE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is fixed format, why not use substr? `year1` is extracted using `substr(s,1,4)`, `id1` is extracted using `substr(s,9,9)` and the `id2` as `as.numeric(substr(s,10,13))`. In the last case I used `as.numeric` to get rid of the zeroes.

Comment: Thanks mpiktas, should have thought of that. I am however still curious as to why the lookbehind does not work...

Answer (score 9):

You will need to use `gregexpr` from the `base` package. This works:

```
> s <- "199719982001"
> gregexpr("^\\d{4}|\\d{1}(?<=\\d{3}$)",s,perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1]  1 12
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 4 1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Note the `perl=TRUE` setting. For more details look into `?regex`.

Judging from the output your regular expression does not catch `id1` though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub.

```
sub("^(.{4}).{4}(.{1}).*([1-9]{1,3})$","\\1\\2\\3",s)
```