# Combining regex with a literal string

Tags: regex, r

I have the following code:

```
input <- "1-FA-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-EX-1-I2-1-I3-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I3-1-I1-1-FA-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3-1-FA-1-QU-1-I1-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-I3-1-QU-1-I2-1-I3-1-QU-1-NR-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-QU-1-QU-1-I2-1-I1-1-EX"

innovation_patterns <- gsub(input, pattern = "-1-", replacement = "-")
innovation_patterns <- lapply(innovation_patterns, str_extract_all, '(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*')
```

This outputs:

```
"I2-I3"    "I3-I1"    "I3-I2"    "I2-I1-I3" "I3"       "I2-I3"
```

However, I only want to extract matches to the regex that are following immediately to a specific string, e.g.:

*only match the regex when it's preceded by the literal string* `FA-I2-I2-I2-EX`.

This, for example, would be the first match of the regex, while the second match is preceded by `FA-I1-I2-TR-I1-I2-FA`.

The expected output is roughly the same as in the regex above, but only selecting one of the 5 matches, because it needs to be preceded by a specific literal string.

How can I modify this regex to achieve this purpose? I assume it needs to use a positive lookbehind to first identify the literal string, then execute the regex.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: But there isn't a sub string `FA-I2-I2-I2-EX` .

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Once you do `innovation_patterns <- gsub(input, pattern = "-1-", replacement = "-")` there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to implement it:

```
lapply(innovation_patterns, str_extract_all, '(?<=FA-I2-I2-I2-EX-?)(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*');
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
## [1] "I2-I3"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'm fully understanding what you mean, but it seems you could use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

For instance:

> `(?<=a)b` (positive lookbehind) matches the `b` (and only the `b`) in `cab`, but does not match `bed` or `debt`

Comment: Yes, it needs a positive lookbehind, questin is how to implement it.

Comment: For that [the second answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834872/r-regular-expression-lookbehind) might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, or better the third by mpiktas

Answer (score 2):

Use `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
innovation_patterns <- gsub(input, pattern = "-1-", replacement = "-")
innovation_patterns <- lapply(innovation_patterns, str_extract_all, perl('FA-I1-I2-TR-I1-I2-FA.*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*'))
```

Syntax would be like,

```
 partIDontWant.*(*SKIP)(*F)|choose from the string which exists before partIDontWant
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mG2aX6/1)

Comment: I can't get this to work in R: `Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)`

Comment: think it would be `perl('FA-I1-I2-TR-I1-I2-FA.*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*')`

Comment: I think the `(*SKIP)(*F)` have some problems with `stri_extract_all` (str_extract is using the `stringi` library).  The `perl(...` still gives me error.

Answer (score 2):

There should be something more intuitive but i think this will do the job

```
literal <- "FA-I2-I2-I2-EX"
innovation_patterns <- gsub(input, pattern = "-1-", replacement = "-")
a <- lapply(strsplit(innovation_patterns, literal )[[1]], str_extract_all, '(?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*')
b <- lapply(2:length(a), function(x){
           a[[x]][[1]][1]
     })

print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's is another way you could go about this.

```
x <- "1-FA-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-EX-1-I2-1-I3-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I3-1-I1-1-FA-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3-1-FA-1-QU-1-I1-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-I3-1-QU-1-I2-1-I3-1-QU-1-NR-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-QU-1-QU-1-I2-1-I1-1-EX"
```

**CODE**

```
substr <- 'FA-I2-I2-I2-EX'
regex <- paste0(substr, '-?((?:I\\d-?)*I3(?:-?I\\d)*)')
gsubfn::strapply(gsub('-1-', '-', x), regex, simplify = c)
## [1] "I2-I3"
```