# Extract character before and after "/"

Tags: regex, stringr, stringi

I'm trying to extract character before and after "/" with no success. Sentences are:

```
XXXX YYY ZZZ - AV HAHEHRS, 3061 - SDDW ASDA DDSF - SAO JOSE DOS CAMPOS / SP - CEP: 00000-000
```

Output should be

```
SAO JOSE DOS CAMPOS / SP
```

I'm trying `str_extract(str, "- [a-zA-Z]{1,} / [a-zA-Z]{1,}")` but it's just bringing me

```
CAMPOS / SP
```

Comment: FWIW, your regex begins with the `-` character. It's unlikely that it returns the match you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex there is the space missing. Try:

```
str_extract(str, "- [a-zA-Z ]+ / [a-zA-Z ]+")
```

Note the space in the character class. Also, `{1,}` is the long form of `+`.

The match will be `"- SAO JOSE DOS CAMPOS / SP - CEP"`. You must get rid of the `-` in a second step, or use a zero-width look-behind:

```
str_extract(str, "(?<=- )[a-zA-Z ]+ / [a-zA-Z ]+")
```

Look-behinds are [supported by `gregexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8834874/18771).

---

For the sake of completeness, you could do this without regex: Split the input by `'-'`, find the part that contains `'/'`, trim. This might be faster than regex, too.