# Extract a pattern before // and after || symbol

Tags: r

I am not very familiar with regex in R.

in a column I am trying to extract words before // and after || symbol. I.e. this is what I have in my column:

```
qtaro_269//qtaro_269||qtaro_353//qtaro_353||qtaro_375//qtaro_375||qtaro_11//qtaro_11
```

This is what I want:

```
qtaro_269; qtaro_353; qtaro_375; qtaro_11
```

I found this: [Extract character before and after "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088845/extract-character-before-and-after) and this: [Extract string before "|"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291794/extract-string-before?noredirect=1&lq=1). However I don't know how to adjust it to my input. Any hint is much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
a  qtaro_269//qtaro_269||qtaro_353//qtaro_353||qtaro_375//qtaro_375||qtaro_11//qtaro_11
b 
c qtaro_269//qtaro_269||qtaro_353//qtaro_353||qtaro_375//qtaro_375||qtaro_11//qtaro_11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following?

```
# Split by "||"
x2 <- unlist(strsplit(x, "\\|\\|"))
[1] "qtaro_269//qtaro_269" "qtaro_353//qtaro_353" "qtaro_375//qtaro_375" "qtaro_11//qtaro_11"  

# Remove everything before and including "//"
gsub(".+//", "", x2)
[1] "qtaro_269" "qtaro_353" "qtaro_375" "qtaro_11"
```

And if you want it as one string with `;` for separation:

```
paste(gsub(".+//", "", x2), collapse = "; ")
[1] "qtaro_269; qtaro_353; qtaro_375; qtaro_11"
```

Comment: in my column I have also empty rows without qtaro etc, and when I do x2 all rows seem to be full...I don't know if I am making smth wrong

Comment: Not sure if I understand. This is not working on your data? Perhaps share more complete example of your data then?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. For sure not the most intelligent and elegant way, so suggestions to improve it are welcome.

```
df <-unlist(lapply(strsplit(df[[2]],split="\\|\\|"), FUN = paste, collapse = "; "))
df <-unlist(lapply(strsplit(df[[2]],split="\\/\\/"), FUN = paste, collapse = "; "))
df <- sapply(strsplit(df$V2, "; ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = "; "))
```