# Extract characters within certain symbols

Tags: python-3.x

I have extracted text from an HTML file, and have the whole thing in a string.

I am looking for a method to loop through the string, and extract only values that are within square brackets and put strings in a list.

I have looked in to several questions, among them this one:  [Extract character before and after "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088845/extract-character-before-and-after)

But i am having a hard time modifying it. Can someone help?

**Solved!**

Thank you for all your inputs, I will definitely look more into regex. I managed to do what i wanted in a pretty manual way (may not be beautiful):

```
#remove all html code and append to string
for i in html_file:
    html_string += str(html2text.html2text(i))

#set this boolean if current character is either [ or ]
add = False

#extract only values within [ or ], based on add = T/F
for i in html_string:
    if i == '[':
        add = True
    if i == ']': 
        add = False
        clean_string += str(i)
    if add == True:
        clean_string += str(i)

#split string into list without square brackets
clean_string_list = clean_string.split('][')
```

The HTML file I am looking to get as pure text (dataframe later on) instead of HTML, is my personal Facebook data that i have downloaded.

Comment: Will you ever have a situation where there are nested brackets? For example:

`hello [ hi bye [ nice ] to meet ] you`

Comment: Can you show the contents of the file?

Comment: @mahir it is my personal comments.html file that i have downloadet through facebook. Depending on the progress Ill make ill post my 'fb file converter' to github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this regex, given a string it will place all text inside [ ] into a list.

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'\[(\w+)\]','spam[eggs][hello]'))
>>> ['eggs', 'hello']
```

Also this is a great reference for building your own regex. 
https://regex101.com

EDIT: If you have nested square brackets here is a function that will handle that case.

```
import re
test ='spam[eg[nested]gs][hello]'

def square_bracket_text(test_text,found):
    """Find text enclosed in square brackets within a string"""
    matches = re.findall(r'\[(\w+)\]',test_text)
    if matches:
        found.extend(matches)
        for word in found:
            test_text = test_text.replace('[' + word + ']','')
        square_bracket_text(test_text,found)
    return found

match = []
print(square_bracket_text(test,match))
>>>['nested', 'hello', 'eggs']
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how i could find the text between: <div class="_3-94 _2lem">  TEXT </div> ?

Comment: BeautifulSoup helped me out: for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : '_3-94 _2lem'}):
    print(i)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `re.finditer()` for this,  see below example.

> Let suppose,  we have word characters inside brackets so regular expression will be `\[\w+\]`.
>
> If you wish,  check it at https://rextester.com/XEMOU85362.

```
import re

s = "<h1>Hello [Programmer], you are [Excellent]</h1>"
g = re.finditer("\[\w+\]", s) 
l = list() # or, l = []

for m in g: 
    text = m.group(0)
    l.append(text[1: -1]) 

print(l) # ['Programmer', 'Excellent']
```